# .Net Core Kestrel Hitting A GET Limit for JSON Data

Tags: json, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm busy adjusting the limits on a .Net Core Kestrel Application to allow large amounts of JSON data to be sent through a GET Request.

```
builder.UseKestrel(options => {
    int oneByte = 1048576;
    options.Limits.MaxRequestLineSize = (4 * oneByte);
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBufferSize = (4 * oneByte);
    options.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = (4 * oneByte);
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = (10 * oneByte);
});
```

So I've set pretty much everything to a 4MB Limit (except MaxRequestBodySize) but I am still hitting a limit on about 2.1MB of JSON data. I know it's not normal to be using such a large amount of JSON data in a GET Request but why is it still being limited when it's under my 4MB threshold?

Is it possible that it is being limited on the number of properties in the JSON data instead of the size and is there any way to increase this limit?

Comment: Could you test, to set the MaxResponseBufferSize to null

Comment: Setting the MaxResponseBufferSize to null seemed to have the same problem

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @AtomicallyBeyond I did but forgot to post it, I will post what I did now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up getting this working was including these settings in the services configure

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => {
        options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
        options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        options.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
        options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    });

}
```